# SOAPHandler vs LogicalHandler

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

Can anybody explain, why do we need `LogicalHandler` if we can do much more with a `SOAPHandler` in `JaxWs`?

Answer (score 1):

From the JAX-WS 2.2 [spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxws-2.2-mrel3-evalu-oth-JSpec/jaxws-2_2-mrel3-spec.pdf):

> JAX-WS 2.0 defines two types of handler:
>
> **Logical** Handlers that only
>   operate on message context properties and message payloads. Logical
>   handlers are protocol agnostic and are unable to affect protocol
>   specific parts of a message. Logical handlers are handlers that
>   implement javax.xml.ws.handler.LogicalHandler. Protocol Handlers that
>   operate on message context properties and protocol specific messages.
>
> **Protocol** handlers are specific to a particular protocol and may access
>   and change protocol specific aspects of a message. Protocol handlers
>   are handlers that implement any interface derived from javax.xml.ws-
>   .handler.Handler except javax.xml.ws.handler.LogicalHandler.
>
> ...
>
> Handlers for protocols other than SOAP are expected to implement a
>   protocol-specific interface that extends javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler.

So in short, if you need nothing to do with anything SOAP, you don't need to implement `SOAPHandler`.  One use case might be a handler that only processes HTTP headers, attachments, or inspects the `HttpServletRequest`.  Yes, you can do much more with `SOAPHandler` but sometimes you don't need access to SOAP headers, `SOAPMessage`, or payload DOM access.